# Why do I encounter a failure to start error when I start Rabbitmq in the virtual machine?

Tags: rabbitmq

Operation System : CentOs7 VMVare Virtual Machine

Execute command `sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server` get this error:

```
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Execute command `systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service` and then get this infomation :

```
rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-07-14 04:13:16 EDT; 5s ago
  Process: 49273 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 49273 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Jul 14 04:13:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
Jul 14 04:13:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
Jul 14 04:13:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.
```

Execute command `journalctl -xe` and get the error infomation:

```
Jul 14 03:48:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[48958]: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is 2.
Jul 14 03:48:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jul 14 03:48:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jul 14 03:48:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
Jul 14 03:48:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.
Jul 14 03:48:40 localhost.localdomain sudo[48950]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 14 03:48:40 localhost.localdomain polkitd[568]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:48952:2379712 (system bus name :1.64, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disc
Jul 14 03:48:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 14 03:48:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped RabbitMQ broker.
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has finished shutting down.
Jul 14 03:48:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ broker...
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun starting up.
Jul 14 03:48:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[48960]: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is 2.
Jul 14 03:48:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jul 14 03:48:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jul 14 03:48:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
Jul 14 03:48:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.
```

What is causing this error? and How can I resove?

Thank you!

I write configuration `NODENAME=rabbit@localhost` into configuration file `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` but this can't resolve the problem.